# How to enum 32bit process's modules from a 64bit application

Tags: .net, winapi, dll, c#-2.0

I have the code:

```
        foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses()) {
            if (process.ProcessName.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("iexplore")) {

                foreach (ProcessModule module in process.Modules) {
                    string descr = module.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription;
                    MessageBox.Show(module.FileName);
                }
            }
        }
```

My app is set on "Any CPU" configuration, so it should run as 64bit process on my Win7 x64. I tried to enumerate iexplore.exe's modules (the 32bit version). My question is how to enum the modules of 32bit apps from 64bit app? It returns only the WoW dlls.

Comment: You should check that you actually *are* running as a 64 bit process (either checking `IntPtr.Size == 8` or by looking with Task Manager, Process Explorer, ...). Also, I think `wow64.dll` is the layer used by 32 bit applications on 64 bit windows. So make sure that the iexplorer instance you are watching is really the 64 bit version and not the 32 bit version.

Comment: Did you find a solution that works for you? Looking into your linked questions it seems like the issue is still unresolved, isn't it? If not, have you managed to build a code sample to access all the modules of a running 32-bits application from a 64-bits environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem in my application, although I think you got it backwards (see may comment to your question).

Actually, it is not possible to enumerate the modules of 32bit process on 64bit Windows, if your own process is a 64bit process.

You'll only see the following modules (which are the only 64bit modules in the 32 bit process):

- The main module (i.e. the executable)
- NtDll.dll
- Wow64.dll
- Wow64cpu.dll
- Wow64win.dll

Which is most likely due to the fact that `Process.Modules` uses the [`EnumProcessModules`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 API internally, which has limitations when working with 32/64 bit. MSDN suggests (for native applications) to use [`EnumProcessModulesEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which you could P/Invoke as well.

It [looks like others](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.modules.aspx#1) have discovered this issue as well.

Comment: Too bad I can't seem to find pinvoke example for EnumProcessModulesEx.

Comment: Please see my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486495/how-to-enum-process-modules-in-windows-xp-64bit