# How to enum another process modules in Windows XP 64bit

Tags: .net, winapi, dll, c#-2.0

I already asked how to enum 32bit process modules from a 64bit process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485271/how-to-enum-32bit-processs-modules-from-a-64bit-application). And the answer was [EnumProcessModulesEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). All works fine on Windows 7 x64, but what about Windows XP x64? It seems that this api is supported on Vista and up. So what's the way to do it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CreateToolHelp32Snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will do it.

Comment: I tried Mike Kwan's solution below, and have the same results as the OP - it returns only the 64-bit modules

Answer (score 2):

Probably something like this. Wrote it in notepad so might be wrong. But you get the idea.

```
HANDLE        hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, dwPID );
MODULEENTRY32 me32      = {0};

me32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
Module32First( hSnapshot, &me32 );

do {
  ...
} while( Module32Next( hSnapshot, &me32 ) );

CloseHandle( hSnapshot );
```

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work well if my process is 64bit and the other is 32bit. See here: http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php?PHPSESSID=d214f61d4ffa3a0a9395101e3e913498&topic=9695.0

Comment: So it looks like examining a 64 bit process requires the caller to be 64 bit too.