# .NET Core System.Diagnostics.Process and Powershell Get-Process are missing modules

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, process

I just noticed weird behaviour of .NET Core's Process class - that is, it doesn't list all the modules loaded by opened process.

I tried to look into one of my games and noticed that while .NET Framework and Process Hacker list over 100 modules loaded by game's process, both .NET Core's implementation of Process class and Powershell's Get-Process applet list only 5 modules - the game exe itself, ntdll.dll and 3 wow64 libs.

I of course run all of that code as administrator, to make sure there isn't any problem with permissions.

Did anybody saw such problem and maybe have workaround?

.NET Core version I am working with is 3.1.402, Windows is freshly installed Win 10 Pro, build 2004.

I will try to go through all processes on my PC to find more discrepancies.

Comment: Which version of PowerShell (`$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`)? If > 5.1, is there a difference between Windows PowerShell and newer versions?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen 5.1, build 19041, I'd need to remote to my work PC to see if older PowerShell has the same issue

Comment: Sorry, I meant differences between 5.1 and anything newer (ie. PowerShell Core 6.x or PowerShell 7) :)

Comment: Ok, I created the app that goes through all my processes and in the end I found the core of the problem. 64 bit process (which PowerShell certainly is) can't access 32 bit processes modules, because of https://stackoverflow.com/a/7485360/5951777. Also, some trickery with IIS caused my .NET Core app to be 64 bit instead of 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

After creating console app going through all my processes and listing their module for both .NET Core and .NET Fx I found the culprit.

1. PowerShell is 64 bit process, so it has trouble looking into the modules of 32 bit processes (it probably uses `EnumProcessModules` WinAPI internally, just as `System.Diagnostics.Process` does)
2. Because of some trickery of IIS my .NET Core app, which was configured just like .NET Fx one (Debug, AnyCPU) became 64 bit app, and because of reasons above, it can't access 32bit app's modules, except for some wow64 dll's.
3. .NET Fx app was 32 bit app in the end, so it was also running under wow64, so it was able to see all the modules.|

Solution to the problem? Ditch the `System.Diagnostics.Process` (at least for the modules part) and try to use `EnumProcessModulesEx` WinAPI call, which supposedly is able to see modules under `wow64.dll`. If I will find out how to use one...

Answer (score 0):

publish project for win-x86
or
dotnet run -r win-x86

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).